# SPARQL Restrict Number of Results for Specific Variable

Tags: sparql

Suppose I want to look for some first degree neighbors of Berlin. I ask the following query:

```sql
select ?s ?p where {
  ?s ?p dbr:Berlin.
}
```

Is it possible to put a restriction on the return result, such that there are at most 5 results for each unique value of `?p`?

Comment: that's not possible in SPARQL 1.1, see also a suggestion for SPARQL 1.2: https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/issues/100

Answer (score 0):

My attempts with subqueries all time out...

But, as potentially useful if not exactly perfect solution, maybe `GROUP_CONCAT`, `MAX`/`MIN` or `SAMPLE` are of use?

```
SELECT 
    ?writer (GROUP_CONCAT(?namestring; SEPARATOR = " ") AS ?namestrings) 
    (MIN(?namestring) AS ?min_name) 
    (MAX(?namestring) AS ?max_name) 
    (SAMPLE(?namestring) AS ?random_name) 
    (SAMPLE(?namestring) AS ?another_random_name_that_may_unfortunately_be_the_same_again) 
WHERE {
     ?writer wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
             wdt:P166 wd:Q37922;
             wdt:P735 ?firstname.
  ?firstname wdt:P1705 ?namestring.
}
GROUP BY ?writer
HAVING ((COUNT(?writer)) > 2 )
LIMIT 20
```

See it live [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fwriter%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28%3Fnamestring%3B%20SEPARATOR%20%3D%20%22%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Fnamestrings%29%20%0A%28MIN%28%3Fnamestring%29%20AS%20%3Fmin_name%29%20%0A%28MAX%28%3Fnamestring%29%20AS%20%3Fmax_name%29%20%0A%28SAMPLE%28%3Fnamestring%29%20AS%20%3Frandom_name%29%20%0A%28SAMPLE%28%3Fnamestring%29%20AS%20%3Fanother_random_name_that_may_unfortunately_be_the_same_again%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fwriter%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP166%20wd%3AQ37922%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP735%20%3Ffirstname.%0A%20%20%3Ffirstname%20wdt%3AP1705%20%3Fnamestring.%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fwriter%0AHAVING%20%28%28COUNT%28%3Fwriter%29%29%20%3E%202%20%29%0ALIMIT%2020).

And, as you can see, `SAMPLE` is apparently evaluated only once, so using it repeatedly does not get you closer to five (different) samples.

(You can leave out the `HAVING` for your use. I only included it to restrict it to useful examples))

Comment: which attempt with a subquery would this be? Subqueries are always evaluated first, so you can't get something like 5 per ?p or group: See also suggestions for SPARQL 1.2: https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/issues/100 and https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/issues/9 and https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/issues/47